# Android ExoPlayer deprecated unable to stream video

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

Learning Android ExoPlayer to stream a video and every tutorial I come across seems to be outdated. For example in Code Labs tutorial: DataSource.Factory is deprecated:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/exoplayer-intro/#2

This one: 
https://android.jlelse.eu/android-exoplayer-starters-guide-6350433f256c

the ExtractorMediaSource is deprecated. I saw on Stack someone said to replace with ProgressiveMediaSource but that also has a red squiggly line through the bottom of that.

What can I edit in either tutorial to make it work properly. I'd really like to see if I can get something going on the second one from Android Pub.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: By the way my dependencies are: implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.10.5'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.10.5'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.10.5'

Comment: I know tha feel. I found only one example which is correct and not outdated. This is official sample https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/demos

Comment: I was finally able to get it to work using version 2.8.1. Hope it helps someone else spending way too long on that! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using version 2.8.1 I was able to follow the tutorials I posted above. I didn't experiment with any others after I finally got it to work. Hope it helps someone else!